# Discord.py Checks with Conditions based on empty settings

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have a Bot ready to deploy via Heroku as well as normal Python. I have added roles_id in its app.json as well as in settings.json which can be used with normal hosting. I currently have condition check for all the commands via has_role(ROLE_ID) and execute the command. I want to add if role_id is not mentioned in settings , it should automatically use is_owner() check.

```
@bot.command(name='test', aliases=['tst'])
@commands.has_role(ROLE_ID)
async def _test(ctx):
```

Now i want to use condition checking for all of my commands that if roles_id is not mentioned or empty in its environment it should automatically use is_owner function for check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`check_any`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.check_any):

```
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.command(name='test', aliases=['tst'])
@commands.check_any(commands.has_role(ROLE_ID), commands.is_owner())
async def _test(ctx):
    ...
```

Comment: Yeah i got this working didnt mark as it as working i have another issue because now i have to get specific error to display to client that they are missing roles. How do we add that instead of Check Any all error  condition  ?

Comment: When errors are raised in `check_any`, like [`MissingRole`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MissingRole), it will raise a [`CheckAnyFailure`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.CheckAnyFailure) exception which lists both the check(s) that failed and the errors associated with those failures. You can use that info in your error handler to create a message for the user.  If you  need more help, you can create a new question with some more detail and I can help with the code.